# How to deal with errors in large formsets?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.7

I'm just starting with formsets and I have trouble making a user friendly error system.

So the user sees a list view that shows him all instances of a model already written into a formset. This pages is meant to show him the data and edit it as well.

Before I was using a lot of individual forms with a save button for every form. But now I want to improve it to have a formset that provides a single save button for all of the forms.

But there comes my problem: Before I used to send the user via "action" to another url (e.g. .../update/ ) which processes the request and then sends him back to the list view he saw before. That's to avoid multiple submits when hitting F5.

But now if I do this and only a single form is wrong all the information the user had entered is lost.

So instead I stopped using the extra URL and made the processing part of the list view. Now I can use form.error on every form, but also the user resubmits when hitting F5.

Is there a way to have both?

Also: I have 1 extra form. But if the user changes it, and I feed the POST data into the formset, save it and then put it back to the page I lost the extra formset, because now the former extra is showing the newly entered instance and there is no true extra field left until the page is refreshed without sending post data.

Here is my View:

```
class BVServerListView(View):
  def get(self, request):
    eigene_server = Server.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    EigeneServerFormset = modelformset_factory(Server, extra=1, form=ServerForm)
    eigene_server_formset = EigeneServerFormset(queryset=eigene_server)
    context = {'eigene_server': eigene_server_formset,}
    return render(request, 'bildverteiler/server_list.html', context)
  def post(self, request):
    eigene_server = Server.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    EigeneServerFormset = modelformset_factory(Server, extra=1, form=ServerForm)
    eigene_server_formset = EigeneServerFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    for form in eigene_server_formset.forms:
      if form.data.get('delete', False):
        server = Server.objects.get(user=request.user, name=form.data['name'])
        server.delete()
      else:
        if form.has_changed() and form.is_valid():
          server = form.save(commit=False)
          server.user = request.user
          server.save()
    context = {'eigene_server': eigene_server_formset,}
    return render(request, 'bildverteiler/server_list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between using a single form or a formset here. The answer is the same: post to the same view, but redirect after a successful save.

The other thing that you are doing wrong here is to validate and save individual forms one by one. Don't do that, because you could end up with a situation that the first forms are valid and get saved, but subsequent ones are invalid and therefore the formset needs to be redisplayed. Instead, validate the formset as a whole:

```
if eigene_server_formset.is_valid():
    for form in eigene_server_formset.forms:
        if form.cleaned_data.get('delete'):
            ... delete ...
        else:
            form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('somewhere_else')
return render...
```